# How to get the state of Qcheckbox that is present inside the QGroupbox in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, qcheckbox, qgroupbox

My project contains Qdialog having multiple QGroupbox.Each GroupBox contains some number of checkboxes.The list of checkboxes is same for all the groupbox. I dont have much reputation to load an image :(

Here the user is able to select the checkboxes based on his need and presses the ok button.Once the Ok Button is pressed, I should be able to get the list of checkboxes checked by the user.

I am creating the checkboxes in a loop, here is the code:

```
def createGroupBox(self,livename,shotlist):        

    groupBox = QtGui.QGroupBox("Live-"+livename)        
    grpLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    i=0
    while  i != (len(shotlist)-2):
        qChkBx_shot = QtGui.QCheckBox("Shot-"+shotlist[i], self)
        qChkBx_shot.stateChanged.connect(lambda: self.groupcheckBoxToggled(livename,qChkBx_shot.text()))
        grpLayout.addWidget(qChkBx_shot,QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        i +=1

    groupBox.setLayout(grpLayout)
    return groupBox
```

GroupBox with the below code:

```
def InitUi(self,livelist,shotlist):
    scrolllayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()

    scrollwidget = QtGui.QWidget()
    scrollwidget.setLayout(scrolllayout)

    scroll = QtGui.QScrollArea()
    scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)  # Set to make the inner widget resize with scroll area
    scroll.setWidget(scrollwidget)

    i=0
    length = len(livelist)-2
    x,y=0,0 

    while x <=  math.ceil(length/4):
        for y in range(0,4):
            if (i < (length)):
                groupbox=self.createGroupBox(livelist[i],shotlist)
                self.groupboxes.append(groupbox)
                scrolllayout.addWidget(groupbox, x, y)
            y +=1
            i +=1
        x+=1

    self.Okbutton = QtGui.QPushButton('OK',self)
    self.Okbutton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.buttonPressed())
    self.Okbutton.setMaximumWidth(100)
    layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(scroll)

    layout.addWidget(self.Okbutton,QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
    self.setLayout(layout)        
    self.setWindowTitle("Customized LiveShotLiveSwitching")
    self.resize(1200, 500) 
    self.show()
```

Here my query is, I could able to retrive the value as which groupbox is been activated and I couldn't able to get the list of checkboxes checked under that groupbox.

Can anybody help me to solve this...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make the groupbox the parent of each checkbox:

```
    qChkBx_shot = QtGui.QCheckBox("Shot-"+shotlist[i], groupBox)
```

Now you can iterate over the checkboxes of a groupbox with:

```
    for checkbox in groupbox.findChildren(QtGui.QCheckBox):
        print('%s: %s' % (checkbox.text(), checkbox.isChecked()))
```

And to get the groupbox the checkbox belongs to:

```
    groupbox = checkbox.parent()
```

Comment: Awesome @ekhumoro